# Link TemplateMonster with Flash Moto CMS

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, documentation, content-management-system

I've installed Flash Moto CMS, and I want to link it with any kind of TemplateMonster but I have no idea on how I can do this right now.

So I'm asking you for help !

Any documentation, any video tutorials !!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be very surprised if you find any documentation on this!

I've had a look at Flash Moto CMS and they provide their own template, which seems to suggest that you would have to find out what structure they use for their own template first, then apply that to a TemplateMonster template. Finding documentation is pretty unlikely, so , provided that their license even allow you to do this , this doesn't look like a light undertaking.

On the other hand, I doubt that the TemplateMonsters files have a single interface that would allow them to be adapted to a CMS, my guess is each template will be pretty different and will require a new implementation, but that's just a guess.